# CSS files and images are not loading in mobile browser Laravel

Tags: css, laravel

I have launched a website which is in `Laravel`, the link of the website is [this](http://www.gahancollections.com/). If you open the website from any laptop it will work, but if you open the site from any `mobile browser (chrome)` then the `CSS` and `image files` are not getting loaded.

here is how I am loading the CSS files in `app.blade.php`. Can anyone point out what I am missing or what I need to do? I tried clearing cache, browsed from different mobile phones.

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/responsive.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

> Routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'CustomerController@index')->name('homepage');
Route::get('/gahans-vision', 'CustomerController@aboutus')->name('aboutus');
```

> .htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gahancollections\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.gahancollections.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: depends on the browser, but i'm guessing that having the site on http and not on https is the issue. especialy if you're using an iphone.

Comment: did you write the codes yourself or bought from someone else? It looks like something is wrong

Comment: @N69S but sometimes it works in mobile browsers too, but most of the time it is not

Comment: @OMiShah yes I wrote the codes, and can you please explain what you think is wrong?

Comment: did you make any changes to the .htaccess file? also, which web hosting are you using?

Comment: @OMiShah Added 2 lines to the .htaccess file as below. GoDaddy VPS hosting.

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gahancollections\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.gahancollections.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Comment: What's the need of doing so?

Comment: Without these 2 lines the site was showing `error 500 internal server error`. I have added the .htacess as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem is with the URL. If you try to open http://gahancollections.com it won't work. Notice that the URL is without `www`. And, now if you open http://www.gahancollections.com in your browser it will work. So, the problem should be in your `routes/web.php` file.

Kindly, add your `routes/web.php` file contents so that we can answer accurately.

Comment: Hey, yes you are right, I have added 2 lines from the `routes.php`.

Comment: @ShanBiswas does your ``storage`` and ``vendor`` have ``write`` permission?

Comment: Yes, both are 755

Comment: if you remove those two lines from the htaccess what exact error does show in the error_log file generated by laravel?

Comment: Let me remove the lines, thank you so much for your cooperation.

Comment: Hey buddy, I removed the lines and no error I faced now, don't know what was going on, now the site is opening with or without `www` and from the mobile browsers too. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Have a great time. 

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this problem in the past, try loading your styles without the `asset` helper like this:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The `/` is important.

Comment: This is not a valid answer. What if the user want to use the absolute path instead of relative path?

Comment: You don't know that it's not a valid answer because if you've ever host a Laravel app on Heroku be rest assured the answer that was accepted isn't going to work, besides that's why I emphasized on the `/`.

Comment: I still don't believe the problem is fixed by that answer in my honest opinion.

Comment: My point of saying was different than what you just said.

Comment: To what end my good friend? The only use for that is if your redirecting out to another site and not when your trying to get a file that lives in your `/public` directory. Let's work with facts/best practices and not assumptions of what could be and ifs.

Comment: try hosting a project in a sub folder and link your css and images the way you have answered, you'll know.

Comment: If that is the case then you include it in your path like so `/css/subdirectory/file.css`, unless you're trying to say the `/subdirectory` does not reside within the `/public` directory in which case I can't possibly imagine why you would store site assets elsewhere in a LARAVEL application. Am not going to respond to this again. Wait! i think I get your confusion, but as long as its in the public directory you don't need to specify it in your path`/public/css/...` in LARAVEL, `/css/...` is fine.

Comment: I am talking about hosting a project in a subdirectory , not about storing my css files inside the subdirectory of the public folder.